# Can't fetch json object data

Tags: c#, json

I have this json object that looks like this below but I can't figure out how to acccess the objects data

[image]

I want to access the 5th index like this

> jsonContent[5]
>   error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: looks like it listing object properties, so maybe try it like "jsonContent.quotes"? Also you have not mentioned if you are trying to deserialize this json into some known type or working with dynamics

Comment: Your next question will be why `quotes` is not returning a list of quotes ;)

Comment: Btw the error means that `jsonContent` is not an array but it is an object.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using? If you are using Newtonsoft.JSON, try `jsonContent["quotes"]`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an object rather than array. So try jsonContent["5"] or jsonContent["[5]"] instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is needed, using the JObject library.

```
var currency = (jsonContent["quotes"] as JObject)["USD"].Value<decimal>();
```